# pointer of char array to integer in c

Tags: c, atoi

This is my code:

```
char str[] ="";
scanf("%s",&str);
char * pch;
pch = strtok (str,"#");
printf ("%s\n",pch);
return 0;
```

I need to render an input of "1#2#3" to three integers first, second and third.
My code above tackles only the first variable and prints the first string "1" but i want to save it to an int variable.

I tried:

```
int first = atoi(&pch)
```

But 'first' get's the value 0 instead of 1. How can i parse a pointer of an array char to int?

Comment: It would be `atoi(pch)` not `atoi(&pch)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the precise layout of the input, and the exact number of `int`s, you can simplify this greatly:

```
scanf("%d#%d#%d", &a, &b, &c);
```

Here is a [link to a demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/Rt0enP).

Answer (score 4):

The code has undefined behaviour as `str` is not large enough to handle any input. `str` can hold at most 1 `char` and `scanf()` will append a null terminator when it reads in a string. If the user enters a single character and hits return then `scanf()` will write beyond the bounds the array `str`.

To correct, decide the maximum length of string that is acceptable and prevent `scanf()` by reading more:

```
char str[1024];
if (1 == scanf("%1023s", str))
{
}
```

Note that `atoi()` produces a result of `0` for invalid input or for `"0"`, which is not helpful. Use [`strtol()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) instead or see the answer from [dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335858/dasblinkenlight) for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

You pass a `char*` to atoi(), not a `char**`. Just call it as `atoi(pch)`

Answer (score 0):

You have declared str as char str[] ="";. This would allocate only one byte to str.
Is it working correctly. I hope I am not missing something here.

As for strtok, you need to use it in a while loop
`pch = strtok (str,"#");`
  `while (pch != NULL)`
 `{`
    `printf ("%s\n",pch);`
`pch = strtok (NULL, "#");`
 `}`